# Reading Stereographs

Tags: molecular-structure, symmetry, crystallography

On an old paper, I found an interesting representation of some symmetry operations: stereographs.

Online I found a set of symmetry operations and related stereographs (see: http://newton.ex.ac.uk/research/qsystems/people/goss/symmetry/Stereographs.html), yet it's  not clear to me how the representation is related to the symmetry operations (or: how are the representations obtained?).

Some samples from the website linked above:

- **C4**

  [image: C4]
- **C5h**

  [image: C5h]
- **D6**

  [image: D6]

I would like to understand the geometrical (and symbolical) meaning of a stereograph, in order to relate non-mnemonically it to its symmetry operation

Comment: Just to be clear: You are asking about the difference between things like $\oplus$ and $+$?

Comment: Not only that. Apparently, although I couldn't find a complete description, stereographs are obtained via "mathematical" projection over a sphere of points derived from the symmetry of the object. Then, the location of the points gives the symbol in the stereographs. I think that every strange symbol in a stereograph could be understood in those terms.

I am sorry if the description is terrible, but I couldn't really find anything "complete" about this notation.

If someone could suggest, for lack of a description, a book which explains it, I could make a search in my university's library

Comment: I vaguely remember a book with all the space groups (regarding symmetry in solid state chemistry), which had similar pictures. I just don't remember its name. But maybe this can be of help: http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/misc/symbols.htm

Comment: The books ' The Basics of Crystallography and Diffraction' by C. Hammond, IUCR texts on Crystallography, publ OUP, and McKie & McKie, 'Essentials of Crystallography, publ Blackwell Scientific, both contain chapters on these projections.

Answer (score 2):

The solid elements are the symmetry operations. The plus and open circle symbols show the positions of atoms and their symmetry mates. The center of the circle is the z-axis. The edge of the circle are directions perpendicular to the z-axis. In the examples in the question, all axes are either along z or perpendicular to z. It gets more complex in cubic symmetry, which also has axes in other directions.

[image]

Here, the triangles are three-fold axis along the body diagonals. The symbols are further explained at http://pd.chem.ucl.ac.uk/pdnn/symm2/pntgrp1.htm.